# Renaming Buttons in different Layouts Issue Android/Java

Tags: java, android, xml, button, layout

i created different Android Layout XMLs by copying different Layouts with Buttons, TextViews etc. from one XML to another. Now there is the Problem that when renaming the iD from one Button in one Layout the Button-ID Changes in all Layout XML files. I am a Rookie in programming and my english isn't that good but it would be very nice if someone may help. Searching for this Problem via g00gle doesn't success..

test_layoutA.xml equal to test_layoutB.xml:

```
 <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnChatF"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/testbuttonimage" />
```

If you Need more Information please ask, thank you very much.

Comment: i do rename the Button in the Graphical Layout overview and do update all ressources afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

If you rename by altering XML directly, then IDE will not catch that and won't populate the change. You should either use `Refactor`->`Rename...` function on that field, or rename using `Properties` sheet, while in graphical editor.

Comment: i did the change by using the Properties Shield in Graphical Layout and after updatig the references the ButtonID is changed in all Layout.XMLs.

Comment: if i'd rename it only in the XML i'm afraid ist not clean and i'd have to add it manually to the R.java..

Comment: R.java class is generated, do not modify by hand as it is pointless. You may want to clean the project to force regeneration of that class.

Comment: should i try to create a new Project with copying the XML-codes manually from the 1st Project? Dont know exactly what you mean with "cleaning"..

Comment: No. I mean menu "Project" -> "Clean".

Comment: same Problem still exists, a few Buttons still rename in all XML-files.

Comment: I am seeing this same issue.  Created a new layout, copied the code from existing XML into new layout (as similar design), amend the id of, say a button, in the new layout (in the Attributes section) and it changes the id of the existing at the same time!!!  Can't see a way to avoid this.. hmmm..

Answer (score 0):

I think after playing around with a couple of layouts, the only way to avoid this 'bug' is to use the Text editor (rather than the Attributes editor).